# How would you handle a data recovery case?

Tags: recovery, data-recovery

I am working on a blog-article about data recovery ans I would be interested how you would approach such a case. Let's tell a client pop by with a HDD and need his data recovered...

What exact would you do?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I'd use a computer program that goes through all the bytes of the disk that are marked as unused and finds anything that looks like it might have been a file.

Comment: OK - so you go streight for Recuva, r-Studio, UFS Explorer or some tool like that. Nothing else?

Comment: I'd just look up "linux recover file" and install the first program that I can find  in the repository for it. Knowing the Linux community anything that works with Linux should also work with Windows.

Answer (score -1):

First qeustion is to the client:
What happenned and what are the symptoms?
Not all recoveries are software and hardware recoveries are approached differently.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).